# does genki desu means how are you? or I'm fine?

Tags: english-to-japanese

does genki desu mean "how are you?" or "I am fine"

Comment: Did you see something say it could mean "How are you?"

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: most probably "I'm fine". But it may be used as "how are you?" too, assuming the question mark was omitted.

---

You used the word "fine", which is a good translation for "genki". So here's an example using "fine":

Donald: "Fine?"

Hillary: "Fine!"

In the above scenario, Donald was asking "(Are you doing) fine?". Hillary answered "(Indeed I am doing) fine!". While not fit for a formal conversation, it establishes casual communication. Genki has the same effect:

Donald: "Genki desu？" (Are you genki?)

Hillary: "Genki desu！" (Genki I am!)

---

However basically the one who asks should add a **"ka?"** at the end, to clarify that he/she is asking a question: "Genki desu **ka**?" verbosely expresses "Genki **is it**?" or "Genki **are you**"?

Therefore when you see the phrase "Genki desu", we can't deny the possibility of it being a question, but it probably is a statement saying "I am fine".

If this was a verbal conversation, the pitch accent would help clarify just like how a question mark would.